# How Claims are mapped in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I am new to asp.net core and I am currently working in the multi-tenant application.I am now stuck because i have no idea of how the claims are mapped in asp.net core

[image: image 1]

I am getting the above error when in try to access the claims from `MIdAuthorizedBaseApiController`.

[image: image 2]

Getting claims from `UserController`.

My Doubt is when the claims in jwt token are mapped to "User.Claims".I am getting the claims in `"UserController.cs"` .But i need those claims in `MIdAuthorizedBaseApiController.cs` inorder to set the "`UserContext"`.

The claims are available in `UserController` but the `UserController` itself is inheriting from `MIdAuthorizedBaseApiController`,but the Claims are not populated there.When i try to access it throws an exception.So, when and how the claims in jwt token are mapped.Please refer the two screenshots above to get my question correctly.

UserController.cs

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class UsersController : MIdAuthorizedBaseApiController
{
     [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(BusinessEntities.User))]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(401)]
    public IActionResult Users()
    {
        // Get Tenant Id
        var claimsList = User.Claims.ToList();
        var tenantId = claimsList[4].Value;
        // Set the Claims
        // _claimsHelper.SetClaims(User.Claims.AsQueryable());

        var users = _userManager.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role);//.Where(n => n.TenantId.ToString() == tenantId);

        // Using "LINQ" to Query only the required properties
        var result = from User in users
                     select new
                     {
                        Id = User.Id,
                        UserName = User.UserName,
                        Email = User.Email,
                        PhoneNumber = User.PhoneNumber,
                        // Roles = String.Join(",", (from roles in User.UserRoles select roles.Role.Name))
                     };

        // Return the result set
        if(result != null) {
            return Ok(result);
        }

        return BadRequest(_localizer["2006"]);
}
```

MIdAuthorizedBaseApiController.cs

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class MIdAuthorizedBaseApiController : AuthorizedApiController
{
    public MIdAuthorizedBaseApiController(UserContext usercontext):base(usercontext)
    {
        PopulateUserContext(usercontext);
    }

    private void PopulateUserContext(UserContext usercontext)
    {
        // Getting exception here when i try to populate User.Claims 
        //here
         var claim = HttpContext.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserId");

        //To be replaced with details from token
        //usercontext.UserId = Guid.Parse("3C5CD705-8DA0-4536-856B-9F39A6ABC0FA");
        usercontext.UserId = Guid.Parse("43200003-6972-4849-B80F-81896C3B5505");
        usercontext.Username = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        //usercontext.TenantId = Guid.Parse("28C914CE-C321-4033-BB87-E9C527249503");
        usercontext.TenantId = Guid.Parse("21550810-A8E7-438F-BBF5-CB0755087356");
        usercontext.ServerName = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
```

AuthorizedApiController.cs

```
using Agility.Core;
using Agility.Web.Filters;

namespace Agility.Web
{
  [BusinessExceptionFilter]
  public class AuthorizedApiController : BaseApiController
  {
    public AuthorizedApiController(UserContext userContext);

    public UserContext UserContext { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HttpContextAccessor` to access the claims .

Modify the `MIdAuthorizedBaseApiController` to perform the dependency injection of `IHttpContextAccessor` on the controllers :

```
public class MIdAuthorizedBaseApiController : AuthorizedApiController
{
    public MIdAuthorizedBaseApiController(UserContext usercontext, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(usercontext)
    {
        PopulateUserContext(usercontext, httpContextAccessor);
    }

    private void PopulateUserContext(UserContext usercontext, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        // Getting exception here when i try to populate User.Claims 
        //here
        var claim = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims;

        //To be replaced with details from token
        //usercontext.UserId = Guid.Parse("3C5CD705-8DA0-4536-856B-9F39A6ABC0FA");
        .......
    }
}
```

And the users controller:

```
public class ValuesController : MIdAuthorizedBaseApiController
{
    public ValuesController(UserContext usercontext, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(usercontext, httpContextAccessor)
    {
    }
}
```

In addition , you could refer to below link which shows how to secure your ASP.NET Core using JWT Bearer authentication ,which use `AddJwtBearer` middlerware to validate/decode the JWT token :

https://jonhilton.net/security/apis/secure-your-asp.net-core-2.0-api-part-2---jwt-bearer-authentication/

Comment: Now getting claims as expected.

Comment: Is this the only way to get claims and also why it is accessible with `IHttpContextAccessor` and why not by `HttpContext.User.Claims`.

Comment: @BaskaranS the controller constructor will be executed before the ActionContext has been set, so you won't have access to properties like Context, User . You need to retrieve the userId within the context of a request. Another way is you can accessing the claims in `OnActionExecuting` function.

Comment: @BaskaranS , if the reply helps you , please mark as answer(the green check button)which may help others who meet same problem